# How to update permissionlevel for some folders automatically

Tags: powershell, permissions, inheritance

I've got a library with many subfolders.

It looks something like this:

Folder1
--Folder1.1
----Folder1.1.1
----Folder1.1.2
...
--Folder1.2
...

And so forth.

My Problem:

For example: on Folder1.1.1 a group has edit permissions not inherited from Folder1.1 . Folder1.1.2 has the same.

Is there any way to automatically change the permissions for the group without breaking/restoring inheritance?